# Million iterations per second

Tags: c#, performance

I have a parser that we implemented and I want to compare it to some other commercial parsers. The other parsers are measuring their speed in terms of "million iterations per second." How can I measure the number of iterations for my parser in C#?

Comment: Add a counter to your loop, so that it increments once per iteration. Time the amount of time a certain number of iterations takes to run. Divide the final value of the counter by the time it took to run. Parser for what, by the way?

Comment: run it for a few million iterations, meassuer the time and divide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Example of how to do this on Visual studio
http://www.dotnetperls.com/benchmark

Also to get an acurate result Complie to an Exe and run as a standalone console application, dont run it from inside Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

To make the measurement comparable you need to know what those "iterations" are in the commercial parser.

Once that is calrified, use the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to measure the execution time. Run your parser in the same context as the commercial parser (same application), count the "iterations" (whatever that is in your context) in your parser and calculate the "iterations per seconds" by deviding the count by the measured time.

Answer (score 1):

Add some counter inside your parser. What is "[iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)" itself? It is repeating oart of process.
E.g. if your parser is dedicater to parse phones, then one parsed phone number from gived data is iteration itself. Count this iterations.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is, look at the code of the commercial parser and see how the performance measurement is done by using a tool like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/). Then implement it **exactly** the same way to make it comparable. Otherwise your results will be totally meaningless.